# CSS: drop-up-menu with absolute positioning

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-position

I have been having trouble with a horizontal drop-down-menu with `position: fixed;`, tied to the bottom of the screen (in this sense a 'drop-up-menu').

Since it is a drop-menu, I must specify a `background-color:` to make the menu contents overlap the page contents above, changed from `white;` to `red;` in this demo case. It works fine by now with the second-level container having `position: absolute;`, however the width of the sub-level doesn't reflect its parent - which are generated on basis of the automatically calculated width of the text in combination with `padding-left: 35px;` and `padding-right: 35px;` and therefore unknown - making the end result ugly ≈ different background-lengths for different `ul`-width calculations on basis of its child contents, as long as the `ul`-sublevel menu is `position: absolute;`.

If I change the `display:` setting to `relative;`, the widths of all the drop-ups will be equal to their parent, but then the positioning will get screwed up and go below the page bottom, since this is not a drop-down-menu and therefore an uncommon scenario for linear decoding.

Others suggest suggest that I work with CSS3 and the `rotate`-attribute, but this seems to me more like a hack than an actual, logical solution. If it is possible, I would like to avoid using anything but CSS, as this is a school project and the education is primarily graphical and not oriented towards programming nor scripting.

Here's the code:

### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <!-- irrelevant code removed -->
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <!-- irrelevant code removed -->
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <p>
            <!-- PAGE CONTENT GOES HERE -->
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="hline"></div>
        <ul class="lv1">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Br&aelig;ndeovne</a>
                <ul class="lv2">
                    <li><a href="#">Contura Hand&ouml;l</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Danfire</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">HETA &ensp;&darr;</a>
                        <ul class="lv3">
                            <li><a href="#">Scan-Line</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Scandia</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">VisionView</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">TIPI</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hwam Heat Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Varde Ovne</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Pilleovne</a>
                <ul class="lv2">
                    <li><a href="#">EdilKamin Pilleovne</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Heta Greenfire</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tr&aelig;piller</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Pejseindsatse</a>
                <ul class="lv2">
                    <li><a href="#">HETA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HWAM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">METEOR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SPARTHERM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VARDE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WIKING</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Skorstene</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Tilbeh&oslash;r</a>
                <ul class="lv2">
                    <li><a href="#">Gulvplader</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HWAM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dansk Design</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">R&oslash;gsuger</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Service</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hline"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.hline {
    background-image:       url("../images/menu-fade.png");
    height:                 1px;
    left:                   -140px;
    position:               relative;
    width:                  1280px;
    z-index:                1;
}

#footer {
    background-color:       red;
    bottom:                 0px;
    font-size:              12pt;
    height:                 26px;
    padding-bottom:         10px;
    position:               fixed;
    width:                  1000px;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left:            auto;
    margin-right:           auto;
    width:                  1000px;
}

#footer .lv1 > li > a {
        color:                  black;
        display:                block;
        line-height:            26px;
        padding-left:           35px;
        padding-right:          35px;
        text-decoration:        none;
}

#footer .lv2 > li > a {
        background-color:       red;
        color:                  black;
        display:                block;
        line-height:            26px;
        padding-left:           35px;
        padding-right:          5px;
        text-decoration:        none;
}

#footer .lv3 > li > a {
        background-color:       red;
        color:                  #888a8c;
        display:                block;
        line-height:            26px;
        padding-left:           70px;
        padding-right:          0px;
        text-decoration:        none;
}

#footer ul.lv1 > li > a:hover,
#footer ul.lv2 > li > a:hover,
#footer ul.lv3 > li > a:hover       {
                    background-color:       #888a8c;
                    color:                  white;
}

#footer li a:hover { color: #888a8c; }

/* no separator on last list item */
#footer .lv1 li:last-child { background: 0; }

#footer .lv1 > li {
        background-image:       url("../images/menu-separator.png");
        background-position:    center right;
        background-repeat:      no-repeat;
        display:                inline-table;
        float:                  left;
        height:                 100%;
}

#footer ul {
        list-style-type:        none;
        padding:                0;
}

#footer ul.lv1 {
        height:                 100%;
        margin-bottom:          0;
        margin-left:            2.5%;
        margin-right:           2.5%;
        margin-top:             0;
        width:                  95%;
        z-index:                2;
}

#footer ul.lv2 {
        display:                none;
        z-index:                3;
}

/* fix margin for first drop-up menu */
#footer li:first-child > ul.lv2 { margin-left: 0px !important; }

#footer li:hover > ul.lv2 {
            bottom:                 35px;
            display:                block;
            position:               absolute;
            padding-bottom:         10px;

            /* align drop-up edge with separator line */
            margin-left:            -1px;
}

#footer ul.lv3 {
            display:                block;
            width:                  100%;
            z-index:                4;
}

#footer li:hover > ul.lv3 {
            display:                block;
            position:               relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position your top-level `LI` relative, and give the second-level `UL` a width of 100%:

```
#footer .lv1 > li {
  /* … */
  position:relative;
}
#footer li:hover > ul.lv2 {
  /* … */
  bottom:26px;
  width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7tALM/3/

(And next time, please provide a fiddle with your code yourself.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! So confusingly many attributes and values when you're inexperienced in menu styling. I'm new here, but I will remember the fiddle next time :)